# Openshift django-mysql database contains no table?

Tags: python, mysql, django, openshift

on localhost django automatically creates some table in the database, how to do the same on openshift server, I have even alter deploy script, even then it creates no table in the database.

Comment: What happens when you run `syncdb`?

Comment: what does the deploy script look like? you need to do a `./manage.py syncdb` for the tables to show up

Comment: can i run syncdb in my terminal, because it will store tables in my localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Read and all will be revealed...

http://appsembler.com/blog/django-deployment-using-openshift/